# Listening for ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED

Tags: android, daydream

How would I get my app to listen for when DayDream stops.  When the system stops dreaming it sends the ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED string out.  I have added a BroadcastReceiver in my OnResume and onCreate and neither are used when DayDream stops.  So where should I put my listener?  I do apologize if I am calling something by its wrong name, I haven't worked with DayDream before.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mDreamingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED)) {
                // Resume the fragment as soon as the dreaming has
                // stopped
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainWelcome.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    };
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BroadcastReceiver` can be created in your `onCreate`.

Ensure you register the receiver with: `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)` and that you've got the `intent-filter` inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Sample:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.toString();

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, TAG + " received broacast intent: " + intent);
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "received dream stopped");
                }
            }
        };

        filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED");
        super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.daydreamtester.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: What is new PlaceholderFragment()?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to register receivers.  Can you explain the if statement.  I don't understand what you are doing in there

Comment: Oh sorry, that just comes from the default Android app template (copy/pasted). You don't need it for this particular example - I'll edit.